# Top align icon in row

Tags: flutter

I have a simple row in Flutter where I display an icon, then some padding, followed by some text wrapped in an Expanded widget.

When the Expanded text wraps, the first icon moves down to the bottom instead of staying at the top of the row? I have wrapped the icon in an Align widget, but it does not seem to work and I can't find anything on this online that works?

On the attached Chicken & Beer screenshot, the icon should be right next to the "10%" text, just as it is when the text hasn't wrapped (see the other Brotzeit screen).

[image]

[image]

```
Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Align(
                                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                            child: Icon(
                                              Icons.thumb_up,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            )),
                                        Padding(
                                            padding:
                                                EdgeInsets.only(right: 20)),
                                        Expanded(
                                            child: Text(
                                                widget.data[0]['Deal_Offer'],
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: globals
                                                        .cardSubTitleColor,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    fontSize: 18)))
                                      ],
                                    )
```

Hope someone can help!

EDIT: Forgot the images.. Duh..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` to your `Row` widget. It aligns a Row's childrens to the top.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for as I would prefer the icon top-aligned, but its a lot better Han what I had. Thanks!

Comment: For top align `CrossAxisAlignment.start` would probably do the trick